# Android createBitmap in onDraw method

Tags: android, bitmap, ondraw

I know it is not recommended to create any object during `onDraw()` method so I am looking for another way how to solve this. Let's say I have a camera stream, then I do some object detection using OpenCV library inside `onPreviewFrame()`.

During `onDraw()` method I need to iterate over all the detected objects, crop them from the input image and scale each one of them and then draw this cropped bitmap on the original bitmap.

My current solution requires 2 bitmaps - one is the original, the other one is used for drawing (I don't draw on the original because there could happen that I would crop something from the part of image where the new objects was already drawn).

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  super.onDraw(canvas);

  canvasTmp.setBitmap(mBitmap);

  for (Object o:objects) {
    Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmapCopy, area_to_crop...);
    croppedBmp Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(croppedBmp , new_size...);
    canvasTmp.drawBitmap(croppedBmp, new_position)
  }

  canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, bitmapPaint);    
}
```

Creating `mBitmap` and `mBitmapCopy` isn't so expensive operation as I am using `setPixels()` method but I was wondering if there is any way how to get rid of recreating bitmap on each iteration?

Thanks